# Do I need a visa to enter South Korea?

Tags: visas, south-korea, uk-citizens

Do I need a visa to enter South Korea as a tourist for a few days travelling on a British passport? My husband is working in South Korea and I'm going out to visit him for a few days and I'm unsure as to whether I need to apply for a visa.

Answer (score 10):

If you have a British Citizen passport you can enter South Korea as a tourist for **up to 90 days without a visa**.

Sources:

- [Korean ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mofa.go.kr/ENG/visa/application/index.jsp?menu=m_40_10)
- [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/south-korea/entry-requirements)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_British_citizens)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much for your help.